# MessageBox not working on PageLoad

Tags: asp.net, message

I am trying to do a Messagebox.show on my asp.net page load event, and I can't see the messagebox object in IntelliSense.

How come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MessageBox is meant for desktop applications, not web applications.  See [this article](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=88) for creating popups for web applications.

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox is meant for WinForms model. You can use this instead: [A Simple ASP.NET Server Control: Message Box & Confirmation Box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/NingLiangSimpleControl.aspx). If you've implemented it you can do calls like this:

```
msgBox.alert("Hello world!");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a message in asp.net you can use the label control. Eric is right messagebox is for desktop apps.